# req.protocol never gives https behind nginx proxy

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, https

I'm trying to recognise whether my express app is serving over an **https** protocol.

Using **nginx** to handle the certification and encryption (on the same machine), and forward requests, `req.protocol` evaluates to `http` even when https is being used and working fine.

I've tried both of the following (individually):

```
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');
```

and

```
app.enable('trust proxy');
```

Yet `req.protocol` still reports `http`.

What gives?

Here's `req.header`:

```
{ 'x-real-ip': '196.38.239.10',
  'x-forwarded-for': '196.38.239.10',
  host: 'idwork.co',
  'x-nginx-proxy': 'true',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '0',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  origin: 'file://',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Postman/4.3.2 Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Electron/0.36.2 Safari/537.36',
  'postman-token': 'redacted',
  accept: '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'accept-language': 'en-US' }
```

Here are my relevant(?) nginx forwarding rules:

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:1234;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I needed to add this to my nginx block:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

Comment: it worked like a charm, thanks. But you should use `protocol = req.secure ? 'https' : 'http'`