# In express.js req.protocol is not picking up "https" for my secure link. It always picks "http"

Tags: node.js, express

req.protocol is not picking up "https" for my secure link. It always picks "http"
. For creating my baseURL am using this. any solutions please?

Comment: Well how are you terminating TLS?

Comment: One alternative is to not hardcode your baseurl. Instead use relative urls. You have several options 1. relative url: "/foo/bar", 2. protocol relative url: "//mysite.com/foo/bar". Relative url will automatically use the same domain as the parent html page. Protocol relative url will automatically use the same protocol (http or https) as the parent html page.

Comment: @slebetman " exports.getHost = function(req){ 
    var baseURL = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host'
 return(baseURL);
} "  this is my code but it always taking the base URL as http when i request with https .

Comment: @SreekanthPM can you mark my answer as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That's happening most probably because there is a proxy in between. In my case I am using Heroku.

If that's the case, you need to add `app.enable('trust proxy');` to your express app.

Without enabling that, `req.protocol` returned `http`. After that change I got `https`.

You can also use `req.secure` to get `true` or `false` depending on if your app is secured by https or not.

Comment: This worked great! i was starting to scratch my head for this issue. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks! I was in despair until I've found your solution!

Comment: Are there any dangers to enabling `trust proxy` setting.  This is the exact solution I needed but want to understand more about what this setting might enable.

Comment: @SKeney here you can see the effects of turning that on: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html

Comment: I also do use heroku. I just solved it by using "https" in production mode as urgent solution. Yours are more clean.

Comment: If you are behind an nginx proxy, you must also follow the instruction of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38028110/3671939)