# Http redirect loop Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code for attempting to redirect any `http` traffic to the equivalent `https`

```
// Add some redirect logic to ensure that https is always used in production, staging, development environment
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // if NODE_ENV is 'local' don't redirect to https, only do so for our deployed server environments
  if(!['development', 'staging', 'production'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV)) return next()

  if(!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect(301, `https://${req.headers.host}${req.originalUrl}`)
  }

  next()
})

/**
 * Bootstrap routes
 */
require('./routes')(app)
```

However, when I go to test this in the browser and input something like `http://example.com` I get a warning in the browser of a redirect loop and in my papertrail logs I can see the console.log firing many times over and over again.

Am I missing something simple here?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: well thats usually the job of an reverse proxy like nginx to redirect your http to htttps

Comment: Why did you think you would not see it many times? If you only want to log on redirect, it's in the wrong place. Note you can use https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.secure.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would imagine I would see it at most twice if I make a get request to `http://example.com`.  Once for the first execution and then for the second after the `redirect` is called.  But if I don't make more requests the log shouldn't keep firing forever.

Comment: @jonrsharpe also tried with `req.secure` and the same thing is occuring.  Infinite loop of redirects.

Comment: And what happens when `https://example.com` loads? Is it just a single plain HTML file, or does that then make requests for stylesheets and scripts?

Comment: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/ff3c5d4065240817012a1a7cc86675655db7cad9/server/middleware.js#L16-L21 does a similar thing and works fine.

Comment: right now I am just serving back static json.  So after the initial GET request no other requests fire off.

Comment: also altered my above code some more to make things a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this StackOverflow: [In express.js req.protocol is not picking up "https" for my secure link. It always pics "http"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459511/in-express-js-req-protocol-is-not-picking-up-https-for-my-secure-link-it-alwa)

Adding an `app.enable('trust proxy')` fixed the issue and allowed the above code to work.  Similarly I'm using Heroku.

Comment: Ah, in the example I shared that's applied where the middleware is used: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/ff3c5d4065240817012a1a7cc86675655db7cad9/server/app.js#L18-L21

Answer (score -2):

try adding `:` to protocol name in `req.protocol === 'https:'`.

```js
// Add some redirect logic to ensure that https is always used in production, staging, development environment
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('here')
  // if NODE_ENV is 'local' don't redirect to https, only do so for our deployed server environments
  if(!['development', 'staging', 'production'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV)) return next()

  // request was via https, so do no special handling
  if(req.protocol === 'https:') return next(); // <---- here, add : after https
  res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
})

/**
 * Bootstrap routes
 */
require('./routes')(app)
```

UPD: its because url parser returns protocol as `https:`. See this examples from nodejs repl mode

```
$ node
> url.parse('https://ya.ru')
Url {
  protocol: 'https:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'ya.ru',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'ya.ru',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/',
  href: 'https://ya.ru/'
}
```

`https:`, not `https`, like mentioned in comments

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.secure suggests the colon shouldn't be there

Comment: Express doesn't use url.parse to determine the protocol, so that example isn't relevant: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/request.js#L292-L324. Again, my comment was that the colon *shouldn't* be there.