# Trying to get the full url of a page

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get the full url of a page using nodejs. I have the following code

```
function fullUrl(req) {
    return url.format({
        protocol: req.protocol,
        host: req.get('host'),
        pathname: req.originalUrl
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, even though the page is https, it returns the url as http. http://www.test.com when it should be https://www.test.com. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried just req.url and see whats in that? You may have to separately grab the protocol port etc and build the url you seek.

Comment: check this [in-express-js-req-protocol-is-not-picking-up-https-for-my-secure-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459511/in-express-js-req-protocol-is-not-picking-up-https-for-my-secure-link-it-alwa)

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable proxy if you are behind one. add `app.enable('trust proxy')`