# Google App Engine Node app not sending cookies in header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-app-engine, express-session

I have a Node app that I've deployed in Google App Engine. I am utilizing sessions in the back end to handle authorization to access certain features.

I'm using `connect-pg-simple` to handle my postgres datastore, and I can see in the database that sessions are being stored in it.

```js
// Connect to DB
const pool = new Pool({ connectionString });

// Create store
const store = new (require('connect-pg-simple')(session))({pool: pool});

// Set up sessions
app.use(session({
    name: "recipebook-session",
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 2592000000, // 30 days
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'none'
    },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store,
    resave: false
}));
```

During the login process, I save a cookie with a CSRF Token to compare with later and send the cookie back to the host:

```js
// Generate tokens
let tokens = auth.generateTokens();

// Save CSRF to user session
req.session.csrf = tokens['CSRF'];

// Return tokens to webapp
res.send(tokens);
```

Client then sends back token:

```js
// Send response to server
let data = await fetch(`https://backend.jeffreycarr.dev/auth/google/verify_login?csrf=${csrf}&code=${code}&scope=${scope}`, {credentials: 'include'});
```

This all works great locally, but trying to do it deployed in App Engine results in the cookie never getting set (and never being told to be set)
[image]

I have a feeling it has to do with the cookie needing to be secure, but I'm using a custom domain with Google and the Google managed certificates are in place. I can access any endpoints on the backend, the cookies just aren't being set.

EDIT

Another attempt I've had is setting the domain on the cookie. The backend is hosted on `subdomain1.primarydomain.com` and the frontend is hosted on `subdomain2.primarydomain.com`, so it is cross domain. Unfortunately setting the cookie domain to `.primarydomain.com` hasn't made any changes, but this could still be contributing to the larger problem at hand.

EDIT 2

After checking what protocol was being sent to the api endpoints, every request was set to `http` despite the frontend and backend being hosted on `https` sites. After some searching, I used `app.enable('trust proxy')`, and now the requests are all `https` but I am getting a CORS error.

Comment: Have you checked this [github thread](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16922#issuecomment-849980690)

Comment: I tried applying the handler rules, but there didn't seem to be any change

Answer (score 1):

In the end, it was because when you run an app on Google's App Engine, it is behind a proxy. Using the answer from this question: [In express.js req.protocol is not picking up "https" for my secure link. It always picks "http"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459511/in-express-js-req-protocol-is-not-picking-up-https-for-my-secure-link-it-alwa), I was able to get it to force `https` and successfully set cookies in my app.